# How can I build and run a .devcontainer folder outside vscode?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

VS Code has this cool feature where you can create devcontainers which leverage docker and can help your team build software in a containerised and unified way - [context](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers). However, I want to also use the dev containers outside of VS Code. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a script that does this. It take the existing devcontainer.json and runs the container in docker. You find more information here https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/run-devcontainer-outside-of-visual-studio-code/